# easyui rowdata how to get value of column by index of the column but not field?

Tags: javascript

I don't want the '0' when the "指标4名称" is null.

below is my js code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
first[12+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_mc';
  first[12+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'名称';
  first[12+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
  first[12+4*i]['width'] = 150;
  
  first[13+4*i] = new Array();
  first[13+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_ysz';
  first[13+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'运算值';
  first[13+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
  
  first[14+4*i] = new Array();
  first[14+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_df';
  first[14+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'得分';
  first[14+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
  first[14+4*i]['formatter'] = function(value, rowdata, rowindex){
   if(row[12+4*i] == ""||rowdata[12+4*i]==null){
      return null;
     }else{
      return value;
     }
  };
  
  first[15+4*i] = new Array();
  first[15+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_ms';
  first[15+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'风险描述';
  first[15+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
```

I just want to know how to get the value of 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_mc',because I couldn't get it by rowdata.field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the value of 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_mc',but I figured my questions out.
code as below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     var flag;
     first[12+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_mc';
  first[12+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'名称';
  first[12+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
  first[12+4*i]['width'] = 150;
     first[12+4*i]['formatter'] = function(value,rowdata,rowindex){
        if(value=="" || value==null){
           flag = true;
        }else{
           flag = false;
        }
        retrun value;
      }  
      first[13+4*i] = new Array();
      first[13+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_ysz';
      first[13+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'运算值';
      first[13+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
  
      first[14+4*i] = new Array();
      first[14+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_df';
      first[14+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'得分';
      first[14+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
      first[14+4*i]['formatter'] = function(value, rowdata, rowindex){
   if(flag){
      return null;
     }else{
      return value;
     }
  };
  
      first[15+4*i] = new Array();
      first[15+4*i]['field'] = 'fxzb'+(i+1)+'_ms';
      first[15+4*i]['title'] = '指标'+(i+1)+'风险描述';
      first[15+4*i]['align'] = 'center';
```